# Plot a different line for each row of a data frame in R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, ggplot2

My question could be elementary yet it has been giving a lot of headache for the last many hours, thus any help would be very much appreciated.

I have a data frame with ~150 columns and ~1000 rows. Each [i,j] cell of the data frame contains a numerical value, apart from the values in the 1st column of the data frame which contain a unique ID (unique for each row of the data frame)

I would like to draw a chart where each row of the data frame would be plotted on a separate chart (plot) on its own (i.e. for each row a plot will be created having its own axis, with the values of the row plotted on the y-axis and the column names of the data frame as labels on the x-axis). Then each of these individual charts will be positioned below the previous one.

For example, if we assume the data frame is the following:

```
Jan = c(2, 3, 5) 
Feb = c(8, 9, 12) 
Mar = c(2.2, 7, 3) 
Apr= c(1, 3.7, 23) 
df = data.frame(Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr)
```

then my goal would be to have 3 plots one below the other, each containing a line passing through 4 points corresponding to the values of each of the 4 months (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr). For example the 1st plot would have a line passing from the values [2, Jan], [8, Feb], [2.2, Mar] and [1.0, Apr]. Similarly for the next two plots.

Could someone point me to the correct direction with some hints on how to meet my goals?

Thank you very much!

Comment: though `plot` instantiates a new plot every time it is called, if you call `segment` it will add on a line segment.  or you can call `points` with the the x variable and find the setting to connect the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `melt` from the `reshape2` package on your example.
It might be harder to have 1000+ facets (rows) and 150+ x-ticks (columns).

[image]

```
df = cbind(df, row_number = seq(1, 3))

df_melt = melt(df, id = "row_number")

ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = row_number)) + 
geom_line(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~row_number, ncol = 1, scales = "free")
```

Comment: Brilliant solution bVa! Thank you so much for your great help! You have totally nailed it !